# Send data from one page (CMS) to subdomain (platform)

Tags: php, cookies, postmessage, grav

I hope, that you are able to help me, or at least give me a few suggestions for a solution.

Context: We have a grav CMS site containing general information, a blog etc (example.com). On a subdomain (test.example.com created in Ruby (backend) and Angular (frontend)) we have a fully developed two-sided platform.

The problem: I need to create a specific landingpage on example.com. This landingpage has to include a signup form, where i need to be able to read the entered data on a subdomain.

Ex: example.com/landing-page1 has a form which contains email, username and password. test.example.com is a fully developed platform, which has a sign-up flow. When submitting the form on example.com, it should open a new window with the test.example.com/sign-up, where the data from the form on example.com is read from.

As i see it, the best solution would be to create a cookie, which can be read from test.example.com. Is that possible?

To do this in grav, as i understand it, i need to create a plugin, that can create this cookie, and then i need to modify the platform so that it can read from the cookie. And i think i need to implement CORS as well to do this.

Any suggestions or help is greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a different approach than above, so I could get out of creating a grav-plugin.
I made the form on example.com send a GET-request to the subdomain, and through that passing the variables through the URL. Then i created a service to store this data, which i then injected in the angular modules, where i needed to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get cookies to share between two domains, though you'll have to do some extra work with the service that creates the cookie. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/1142368) for more details on how that works.

On the Grav side, you're correct. You'll need to implement a plugin (see the dev-tools plugin) that will then read this cookie. If I were doing the project, I would setup the plugin to store the cookie info as a twig variable.

Alternitively, your plugin could simply read from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jacob!
I need grav to create the cookie, but i'm guessing I still need to implement a plugin, which can create this cookie. Then i might not need to store it as i twig variable.
I'll be looking into this problem tomorrow and then i'll post my findings here.